# postcss-svgo: Error in parsing SVG: Unquoted attribute value

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I'm struggling with webpack version 3.
When i'm trying to run webpack in production mode i'm getting this error

```
Error processing file: assets/css/style.css
(node:5388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: postcss-svgo: Error in parsing SVG: Unquoted attribute value
Line: 0
Column: 12
Char: \
    at promises.push.getSvgo.optimize.then.catch.error (project\node_modules\cssnano-preset-default\node_modules\postcss-svgo\dist\index.js:95:19)
```

I have this code inside module section of webpack

```
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
...
            {
                test: /\.svg/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'file-loader' },
                    { loader: 'svgo-loader' },
                    { loader: 'xml-fix-loader' }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [require.resolve('css-loader'), require.resolve('sass-loader')],
                })
            },
...
        ]
      },
```

Please help to fix this issue.